# Convert pandas timestamp to month endate

Tags: python, pandas, date, timestamp, date-formatting

I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(io='http://www.iea.org/gtf/download/Export_GTF_IEA.xls', sheetname='Data', skip_footer=5, )

df = df.drop('Unnamed: 2', axis=1)
df = df.drop('Exit', axis=1)
df = df.drop('Entry', axis=1)
df = df.drop('MAXFLOW (Mm3/h)', axis=1)

df = df.T

df.to_csv('foo.csv', encoding='utf-8', sep='\t', header=False)
```

#

A sample of the output looks like this:

```
print df
                              0        1           2           3        4    \
Borderpoint          Adriatic LNG  Almeria  Alveringem  Alveringem  Badajoz   
2008-10-01 00:00:00             0        0           0           0   152.81   
2008-11-01 00:00:00             0        0           0           0   183.31   
2008-12-01 00:00:00             0        0           0           0    85.21   
2009-01-01 00:00:00             0        0           0           0   199.16   
2009-02-01 00:00:00             0        0           0           0   104.48   
2009-03-01 00:00:00             0        0           0           0     9.17
```

How do I convert the timestamp to a month-end date?

Comment: In your example output the `Borderpoint` column dates are the first date of each month (not the last). Which do you want?

Answer (score 2):

Headers are not set properly so to set proper headers you can use

```
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df.drop(df.index[:1], inplace=True)
```

Den to change the timestamps to month end date you can use

```
df.index = df.index + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0)
```

Output :

```
Borderpoint Adriatic LNG  Almeria Alveringem Alveringem  Badajoz Badajoz  
2008-10-31             0        0          0          0   152.81       0   
2008-11-30             0        0          0          0   183.31       0   
2008-12-31             0        0          0          0    85.21       0   
2009-01-31             0        0          0          0   199.16       0   
2009-02-28             0        0          0          0   104.48      12   
2009-03-31             0        0          0          0     9.17       2   
2009-04-30             0        0          0          0   190.49       0   
2009-05-31             0        0          0          0        0       0
```

Comment: Do accept the answer if you got what you wanted @Max it helps.